# Definition of a Base in Topology.

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking at two definitions for a base.

One https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241217 seems to define a condition for a collection of sets to be a base of **some** topology: 
"Let $X$ be a non-empty set. A collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $X$ is a *base* for some topology on $X$ if it satisfies two conditions:

1. $\mathscr{B}$ covers $X$. That is, every point of $X$ belongs to at least one member of $\mathscr{B}$.
2. If $B_1,B_2\in\mathscr{B}$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, then there is a $B_3\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$."

The other https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Topology/Bases seems to define a condition for a collection of sets to be a base for a **specific** topology: "Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets is called a base for the topology $\mathcal{T}$ if every open set $U$ is the union of sets in $\mathcal{B}$. 
Obviously $\mathcal{T}$ is a base for itself."

It's the second one that's a concern: what does the sets in $\mathcal{B}$ being open mean ?

1. Does it mean that the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are elements of $\mathcal{T}$ ? This would adequately define them as open sets, but would then require that $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{T}$, which I don't think is correct.
2. Alternatively does it mean that $\mathcal{B}$  is a topology in its own right ?

(Or, is there some other explanation for the whole thing that I am missing !).

Comment: In answer to 1, yes! Elements of $\mathcal B$ are elements of $\mathcal T$. In answer to 2, no! $\mathcal B$ is a some collection of sets in $\mathcal T$. It needn't be closed under taking arbitrary union or finite intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the elements of the base are considered open. In the case of the base of a specific topology this means $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal T$, indeed.
   Because the base sets are open we have not only that all elements of $\mathcal T$ are unions of base sets, but also that *any* union of base sets is in $\mathcal T$.
2. No, in general $\mathcal B$ is not a topology. As seen from the first variant we do not require $\mathscr B$ to be closed under arbitrary unions (in fact, neither do we require closedness under finite intersection! And neither $\emptyset$ nor $X$ needs to be in the base!). An example would be: open intervals of length reciprocal to integers form a base of the standard topology on $\Bbb R$, but are not a topology

Comment: Thanks: The empty set is in every topology, so if it is not in the base how is it constructed as a union of sets which are in the base ?

Comment: @TomCollinge it's the empty union. By a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ we mean $\cup \mathcal{B'}$ where $\mathcal{B'} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$. In particular we can take $\mathcal{B}' = \emptyset$